# Nebular - How inject custom strategy validations in `getConfigValue()`?

Tags: angular, typescript, nebular

Why `getConfigValue()` function isn't get validation values from custom Strategies?

Example:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomStrategy extends NbPasswordAuthStrategy {
    protected defaultOptions: CustomStrategyOptions = CustomStrategyOptions;

    static setup(options: CustomStrategyOptions): [NbAuthStrategyClass, CustomStrategyOptions] {
        return [CustomStrategy, options];
    }
}
```

```js
export class CustomStrategyOptions extends NbPasswordAuthStrategyOptions {
    validation?: CustomValidation;
}
export const customStrategyOptions: CustomStrategyOptions = new CustomStrategyOptions();
```

Where `CustomValidation` class contains different fields than `fullName`, `password` and `email`, for example: `name`, `lastName`, `date birth` and `gender`.

In custom `RegisterComponent` in form inputs if you try this:

```js
export class RegisterComponent extends NbRegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('validations', this.getConfigValue('forms.validation');
    }
}
```

The output is `fullName`, `password` and `email` :(

How to inject custom strategy validations in `getConfigValue()` method in Nebular?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
// app.module.ts

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NbAuthModule.forRoot({
            strategies: [ ],
            forms: {
                login: { }
                register: { }   
                validation: {    // Put validations in this level
                    name: { },
                    lastName: { },
                    dateBirth: { },
                    gender: { }
                }
            }
        }),
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```